# Login problems with Access and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I am trying to connect to my database and check the username and login with the database and it keeps failing the login. Any idea what's going wrong?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("You must enter all information.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        Else
        Dim uname As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim pword As String = TextBox2.Text
        Access.ExecQuery("SELECT Password FROM LoginDB WHERE Username= " & uname & "AND Password= " & pword & ";")
        'Try
        'Access.ExecQuery("SELECT Password FROM LoginDB WHERE Username= " & uname & "AND Password= " & pword & ";")
        'Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox("Username does not exist.")
        'End Try
        If (pword = pass) Then
            My.Forms.StableMe1.Show()
            Me.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("Login Failed")
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The database is working in other parts of the code, so I know it's connecting, I just can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: You need to encapsulate username and password in quotes.

Comment: You're not doing anything (one way or the other) to read the results of executing the query. Do you expect it to appear in `pass` by magic?

Comment: @KRichardson even if those are the names of the columns in the datatable I'm looking at?

Comment: @KenWhite I used to have a line that said `Public Function PassFinder()
        Dim passHolder As String = ""
        passHolder = DBCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
        MsgBox(passHolder)
        Return passHolder
    End Function` with a `pass = Access.Passfinder()` but it wasn't working either, so I scrapped it

Comment: I responded as an answer so it'll be easier to see. Hope it helps!

Comment: You scrapped the wrong thing. You now just throw away the results of executing the query, but pretend you didn't. Your code now is the equivalent of sending an email to someone asking for some information, but then adding their email address to your spam filter so you'll never see the response.

Comment: So what is wrong with that code that makes it not work? @KenWhite

Comment: I've told you twice. **You fail to use the result of ExecQuery**. I thought the second time using email as an example would help. You **cannot** just discard the query results. You don't check to see if it returns a row, you don't try to read a row if it returns one, and you try to test an undeclared and unassiged `pass` variable in a test for a matching password. There are literally hundreds of posts here about reading a value from a query result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems I see here, some of which have been mentioned in the comments. You are currently not handling the return of your query, password is being used when it's a reserved word, and the query itself could be tweaked a bit to use parameters and check if the username+password combination exists instead of returning the password. That said, I would say what you need is something similar to the following example. Note that this won't just copy and paste, you will need to fill in your database connection string.

```
'Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("You must enter all information.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    Else
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("your db connection string")
        Dim exists As String = Nothing
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT 'X' FROM [LoginDB] WHERE [Username] = @un AND [Password] = @pw", con)
            With cmd
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", TextBox1.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", TextBox2.Text)
                Try
                    exists = .ExecuteScalar.ToString
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                End Try
            End With
        End Using
        con.Close()

        If exists IsNot Nothing AndAlso exists.Equals("X") Then
            My.Forms.StableMe1.Show()
            Me.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("Login Failed")
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So what this code is doing is connecting to the database, and then querying to simply return a character (just an easy way to check if a record exists when we aren't actually looking to return any row data) if the username+password pair is found in the database. It adds the username and password that the user has entered as parameters so you don't have to worry about spacing or quotes, and also inherently prevents sql injection. Then we just add the parameters, and executescalar which will just return a single value (sqldatareader is unnecessary in this case). Then I just checked if the value is what I'm expecting. Also, just a sidenote, it's not a good idea to store passwords in plaintext...but that's another topic. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to have the user supplied username and password encapsulated in quotes and the fields should also be encapsulated in square brackets (Particularly `password` as it is a reserved word):

```
Access.ExecQuery("SELECT [Password] FROM LoginDB WHERE [Username]= '" & uname & "' AND [Password]= '" & pword & "';")
```

Another issue was a missing space after the username value. The original would have translated into `SELECT Password FROM LoginDB WHERE Username=useraAND Password=password1;`

After you get this working, you will of course need to ensure that the query returned a row, validating the authentication.

To do this, assign the result of `ExecQuery` to a variable, then use `Count`.

```
Set AuthResult = Access.ExecQuery({query})
If (AuthResult.Count = 1) Then
    My.Forms.StableMe1.Show()
    Me.Close()
Else
    MsgBox("Login Failed")
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
End If
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm really know to databases. What type of parameters @soohoonigan? I know what they are, but I'm not how you would use them here

Comment: This does not address the fact that the poster is executing the query, discarding the results, and never assigning a value to `pass` before the comparison. How does the value get out of `Access.ExecQuery` and into the `pass` variable for the comparison? Osmosis? You've detected about half of the issue, which is not enough to constitute an answer.

Comment: Also, if you've fixed the query parameters and it's still not working, it is probably because "Password" is a [reserved word in access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe)... To mitigate that, just put square brackets around the password field name to let access know you are referencing a column name like "and [password] ="

Comment: K Richardson, I did this and its still throwing me an exception. I'm also trying to compare the password in the db to the password in the textbox and I'm not sure which is screwing up

Comment: @KenWhite I explained that in your comment above

Comment: @Sarah: It doesn't matter what you explained in a comment above. This **answer** does not address that issue, and that issue is the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite does that code above not set the pass to the database password?

Comment: @soohoonigan, edited answer to include the square brackets. Also edited answer to address the authentication portion after the query.

Comment: @Sarah: No, it does not. Neither does your code (which I"ve pointed out twice now in comments). This answer addresses half the problem (missing quotes and a space) but fails to address *ensuring that the query returned a row* or *retrieving the value of that row to use in validating the password*.

Comment: @SarahProctor, the code does not set `pass`. I had originally assumed that this was just a placeholder, so I didn't address it. As far as I can tell there would be no reason to return the password from the query anyway, as you already have the user supplied password. Likely what would work is to test the number of rows returned. If 1 then login successful, if 0 then failure.

Comment: @KenWhite pointing out the problems I already know about doesn't quite help me. I know that's where the problems are but you telling me that doesn't help me fix them

Comment: @KRichardson, so like selecting the password from the query and seeing if that is equal to the textbox?

Comment: @Sarah: Flooding my inbox with comments both from your question and this answer aren't helping anything. Rather than just posting comments, **read the words I'm writing**.

Comment: @KenWhite I am reading and rereading but I am obviously not understanding. Could you answer it as an answer instead please?

Comment: @SarahProctor The code as it is checks the user supplied password against the database, all you need to do is check for a result. I've updated the answer. Hopefully it gets you there, though the other answer given addresses these issues plus a couple more.